# assignment from incompatible pointer type in c, for a pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, types, compiler-warnings

I'm rather new to c, and I'm trying to implement a linked list. I wrote this:

```
struct List;
typedef struct List* ListRef;
struct List{
        void *data;
        ListRef next;
        ListRef last;
};

ListRef newList(void* headData);
[...]

ListRef append(ListRef list, void* data){

        ListRef newlist = newList(data)

        list->last->next = newList; //here I get a warning
        list->last = newList;  //here I get a warning

        return newList;
}
```

newList is compiled with no warnings. 
In the two lines with the comments I get:

warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: There is semicolon missing after: `newList(data)`.

Comment: Seriously consider a different name for your local automatic variable `newList` than the *same name* as the function `newList()`. Unless you're purposely trying to obfuscate code, it is a recipe for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
    list->last->next = newList; //here I get a warning
    list->last = newList;  //here I get a warning

    return newList;
```

to

```
    list->last->next = newlist; //here I get a warning
    list->last = newlist;  //here I get a warning

    return newlist;
```

## Analysis:

You have a function named `newList`, which you have mixed-up with the instance of structure you created(`newlist`).

You sure dont code like you are new to C. :)
Hope this helps